# How do I get all the Vector3's between 2 Vector3's?

Tags: lua, roblox

Basically, I want to get all values between 2 Vector3's.

Example:

0,0,0 and 0,3,0 gives: 0,0,0 0,1,0 0,2,0 0,3,0

0,0,0 and 1,3,0 gives: 0,0,0 0,1,0 0,2,0 0,3,0 1,0,0 1,1,0 1,2,0 1,3,0

how can i do this?

Comment: all vectors between 2 vectors doesn't make too much sense mathematically. what problem are you actually trying to solve? also you should at least propose some own ideas as this is not a coding service.

Comment: @Piglet i mean all vectors in steps of 1. look at the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Piglet 's help I made this code:

```lua
local start = Vector3.new(-2,0,0)
local ends = Vector3.new(0,5,0)

function v3fill(pos1,pos2)
    local stuff = {}
    for i1 = pos1.X, pos2.X do
        for i2 = pos1.Y, pos2.Y do
            for i3 = pos1.Z, pos2.Z do
                local vector = Vector3.new(i1, i2, i3)
                table.insert(stuff,vector)
            end
        end
    end
    return stuff
end

local list = v3fill(start,ends)
for i,v in pairs(list) do
    print(v)
end
```

Comment: make sure you start your loops at pos1's coordinates, not at hardcoded 0. you also need to handle the case that pos1's coordinates are bigger than pos2's coordinates.  so you'll end up with something like `for x = math.min(pos1.X, pos2.X), math.max(pos1.X, pos2.X) do`

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't show any own effort to solve this problem I'll just give you a starting point.

Let's say you want all integers between 1 and 10, then you simply run a numeric for loop:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  print(i)
end
```

Getting a combination of integer ranges is just a matter of nesting multiple numeric for loops.